# Is it good to use scoped style for iterated component in Vue

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

We use scoped style in component in Vue and it has advantages.
But suppose I have a component like BoxComponent.vue
and defined one class.

```
<style scoped>
.box-component{
  float: left;
  flex-grow: initial !important;
  margin: 0 3px;
}
</style>
```

I think it might be good to use this in one or twice but when I use this in loop maybe hundreds of loops, then It will generate independent style classes because `vue-loader` will treat each item differently.

In that case I think it could be problem in terms of speed and memory usuage.
Can anybody elaborate this please?
When it is good to use scoped style or global style in Vue.js?

Comment: From what I understand, that's not how it works. Scoped CSS will apply to all instances of the same component, so the style classes are only generated once.

Comment: @yqlim I see. You mean it is always to put the style inside component?

Comment: I think it means that all `<box-component>` will share the one single `<style scoped>` - so if you have hundreds of `<box-component>` that scoped style you've shown is present only once - just like the code in your `script` is present only once

Comment: the only possible speed impact is that `.box-component[data-v-xxxxxx]` selector (which is what scoped style creates) is not as performant as `.box-component` - now, unless you use the class `box-component` to mean different things in different components, then you *may* get better performance if you don't use a scoped style for that class

Comment: @Bravo I think it's actually the opposite, a hashed class is more specific so less work for the CSS repaint. It's like comparing `div` to a `div.hello#world` selector, the 2nd one is more "performant".

Comment: @kissu - the reality, according to many articles I've read, is what I said - I have not "measured" the difference, I wouldn't know how to start. I'm merely "standing on the shoulders of giants" who have claimed this to be the case. So, it's not what "I think", it's what research has taught me (rightly or wrongly)  - in the end, I think the difference is probably imperceptible anyway :p

Comment: @Bravo I'm not agressive or anything here (sorry if you felt so), just saying that I'm 100% sure that more specificity is more performant overall (seems logic because you select a very specific thing rather than a global scope of elements). In a Vue context, with the hash thing it's indeed a bit more complex but still relevant IMO.

Comment: I felt no agression @kissu, not sure why you felt I did!! I don't believe higher specificity === higher performance in the case of a *data attribute* in the selector - at least, that's what I read (or heard) - I'll try to find an article or video that mentions this - again though, I think the *hit* is imperceptible anyway - I use scoped styles when appropriate, but it's usually to change some vuetify styling in a particular component - some vuetify defaults are complete garbage :p

Comment: @Bravo (found somebody who felt attacked by me recently so I try to be careful from now) I do agree on the fact that bloated UI frameworks are bleh and also that the impact performance is meaningless, otherwise it would not be recommended without an actual warning regarding performance.

Comment: @kissu - it could also be a case that these people are conflating `querySelectorAll` performance with style selector "performance" (not even sure how to measure the latter anyway) - and yes, there are some people that seem to feel attacked when you disagree with their opinion - welcome to the internet :p

Comment: @SkyDev Also, you can always just inspect the HTML with browser devtool to see what styles are being generated and how many times it is generated.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the question should be more of a

> Do I need my style to be global here or not?

than a performance one. I'd say that it's pretty meaningless overall, especially if you use an utility framework (like Tailwind). The fact is that you will get less CSS re-definitions across all of your pages.

Choosing how you write your CSS and also what do you exactly use, will have greater impact than scoping or not. Give a read to super-light tools like [UnoCSS](https://antfu.me/posts/reimagine-atomic-css) if you're interested into keeping something super slim.

Also, you will get far more performance hit by 3rd party scripts like GTM, a widget chat or whatever you'll be forced to add by your company anyway.

I don't that runtime CSS will get you poor performance, just don't use super generic selectors like `*` or `div` across your website and you should be fine.

Still, if you have a super huge website, it could be nice to try to benchmark the whole thing somehow by checking the total render time (staying focused on the styling indicators of course): https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/evaluate-performance/

---

Official source: https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements